# Px26-015 pressure sensors output

Tags: electrical-engineering, pressure, sensors

I had a [PC Mountable Wet/Wet Differential Pressure Sensor](http://www.omegaeng.cz/ppt/pptsc_eng.asp?ref=PX26&Nav=preb02)
I used it to measure a pressure difference , I don't know how to convert its output to pressure !

Comment: How is this not directly answered in the datasheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like your sensor is +/-5psid (based on the link you provided), so looking at the datasheet, we have (assuming a 10VDC excitation) 16.7mV at 1psi and 50mv at 5psi. Assuming the sensor is linear (the datasheet states that linearity is +/-0.25% of full scale), you have the following relationship:

```
P = V * 0.1201 - 1.006
```

Where `P` is expressed in psi and `V` in mV. This does not take into account any possible hysteresis (0.2% of full scale according to the datasheet).

If you want an accurate reading, you should probably do your own calibration by applying a series of known pressures (measured with a calibrated instrument, e.g. manometer) and reading the sensor output.

**EDIT**

How did I arrive at the relationship? It's fairly easy, you're fitting a straight line to two points, so you're looking for a slope and an offset:

```
1psi = 16.7mV * slope + offset
5psi = 50mV * slope + offset
```

That's 2 linear equations with 2 unknowns (`slope` and `offset`), which is easily solved to give the values mentioned above. That's really basic maths though, I would expect any engineer or even technician to know how to do that, which is why I hadn't included the details on how to calculate the values in the first place.